# Finding double cosets of a group

Tags: group-theory

I am new to Mathematica, and I would love to know if there is a function that that returns the double cosets of a group $G$ w.r.t a subgroup $H$, where a double coset is defined as $HxH=\{h_1xh_2,\forall h_1,h_2\in H\}$, for some $x$ in $G$. In particular, I am mostly concerned with the the number of such cosets, so it is also satisifiying if there is a function for such countings.
If there's no such general functions, is there special cases for $G$ a symmetric group?

Comment: Arguments about the votes to close this question and opinions about leaving it open are discussed [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2668/10397).

Answer (score 7):

Of course *MMA* don't have any of the functions you need, but we can get the double cosets of a group $G$ w.r.t a subgroup $H$ by it. Such as $S_5$. As we know, $D_5$ is a subgroup of it. Then we can get its double cosets like:

```
G = SymmetricGroup[5];
H = DihedralGroup[5];

Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Outer[PermutationProduct, GroupElements[H], 
    GroupElements[G], GroupElements[H]]]], Less]
TemplateApply["The order of H is <*Length[%]*>"]
```

[image]

> In particular, I am mostly concerned with the number of such
> cosets

I'm not sure I understand this statement of yours. If by definition, any subgroup of G can generate double cosets, so you're actually asking how many subgroups of G are there? For the $S_5$:

```
FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 5}, "Subgroups"]
```

> {Trivial,{CyclicGroup,2},{CyclicGroup,3},{CyclicGroup,4},Vierergruppe,{CyclicGroup,5},{CyclicGroup,6},{SymmetricGroup,3},{DihedralGroup,4},{DihedralGroup,5},{AlternatingGroup,4},{DihedralGroup,6},{SemidirectProduct,{{CyclicGroup,4},{CyclicGroup,5}}},{SymmetricGroup,4},{AlternatingGroup,5},{SymmetricGroup,5}}